# Why do some Entities Refuse Namespacing and fall in Empyt Namespace

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces

I am using the GAE Datastore for the application

I am in despair ... I hit a mental block over here and I just cant think of anything to solve this anymore. I have a class Teacher.class (and all of its CASCADES) that wont store in its Namespace ... all other classes (not shown here, but very similar) work like a charm, the Teacher.class reads and writes and all perfectly ... except if WONT go to its Namespace, it always ends up in the Empty Namespace.

I am going to post the class, along with the data interface layer.

```
@Entity 
public class Teacher implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5426530769458891752L;
@Id
private Key key;
private long KID;
private long school;
private String FName;
private String LName;
private String Email;
private String SchoolName;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Transcript Transcript; // Contains further @OneToMany Relations and Constructors
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private TeacherInfo teacherInf; // Contains Only Primitive Type Objects(not important)
private Boolean ActiveUser = false;
private List<Key> WorkshopsAttended;
private List<Key> WorkshopsRegistered;

public Teacher()//Constructor
{

if(this.KID == 00)
{ 
    this.KID = TeacherUtils.genKID();//Returns a sequence and date and location based long 
    this.key = KeyFactory.createKey(Teacher.class.getSimpleName(), this.KID);
    this.Transcript = new Transcript();
    this.teacherInf = new TeacherInfo();
}

if(this.WorkshopsAttended == null)
{
    this.WorkshopsAttended = new ArrayList<Key>();
}
if(this.WorkshopsRegistered == null)
{
    this.WorkshopsRegistered = new ArrayList<Key>();
}
} //End of Constructor

//Getters and Setters
}
```

Here is the Transcript Class

```
@Entity
public class Transcript implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6677626465437896027L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key ID;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="Transcript",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Teacher teacher;

public Transcript()//Constructor
{
    if(this.C1== null)
    {this.C1= new Course1();}
    if (this.C2== null)
    {this.C2= new Course2();}
    if (this.C3== null)
    {this.C3= new Course3();}
}//End of Constructor

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Course1 C1; // Contains only primitive feilds

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Course2 C2; // Contains only primitive feilds

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Course3 C3;

// Getters and Setters
```

Now Lastly the Data Interface Layer (This is a very long long file and I cant put it all in here, so I am just gonna paste the bits that have to do with persisting Teacher entities)

```
public class TeacherUtils 
{
private static final String ActiveNamespace = SystemSettings.TeacherActive; 
private static final String DeletedNamespace = SystemSettings.TeacherDeleted;
private static final boolean NSFlag = (SystemSettings.UseNameSpace & SystemSettings.TeacherNameSpace);


public synchronized static void SaveTeacher(Teacher teacher)
{
EntityManager em = getActiveEM();
em.persist(teacher);
em.flush();
closeEM(em);
}// End of SaveTeacher

public synchronized static void UpdateTeacher(Teacher teacher)
{
EntityManager em = getActiveEM();
em.merge(teacher);
em.flush();
closeEM(em);
}// End of Update Teacher

private synchronized static  EntityManager getActiveEM()
{
EntityManager em;
try
 {
    if( (!NamespaceManager.get().equals(ActiveNamespace)) && TeacherUtils.NSFlag)
    {   
    setNamespace();
    }

  }
 finally
 {      
    em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
 }
return em;
} // End of getAciveEM();

private synchronized static void closeEM(EntityManager em)
{
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
NamespaceManager.set("");
while(!NamespaceManager.get().equals(""))
{}
return;
}// End of CloseEM(em)

private synchronized static void setNamespace()
{
  if(TeacherUtils.NSFlag)
  {
    NamespaceManager.set(TeacherUtils.ActiveNamespace);
    while(!NamespaceManager.get().equals(TeacherUtils.ActiveNamespace))
    {}
  }
}// End of setNamespace
```

A typical example in the Business Logic Layer would be

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.setFName("John");
teacher.setLName("Smith");
teacher.setEmail("xyz@xyz.com");
TeacherUtils.SaveTeacher(teacher);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone who tried looking into this question ! Turns out there was something wrong with the Teacher.class constructor logic that caused a change in the Namespace, without reverting it to its previous state (the ID generator function). Now that I took care of it all works great !! I think it's just one of those days !!

Again thanks alot and I will be leaving this code as a template incase someone needs it.